# Rails fields_for update not working (deleting the parent object)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for, fields-for

I have `fields_for` form **for update** like below:

```
  <%= form_for @cuisine, url: {action: "update" } do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :name %>

    <% @cuisine.ingredients.each do |ing| %>     
      <%= f.fields_for ing do |ingredient_fields|%>
        <%= ingredient_fields.text_area :name, :value=> ing.name %>
        <%= ingredient_fields.hidden_field :_destroy%>
        <%= link_to_remove_fields 'Remove this ingredient', f %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
```

my cuisines_controller:

```
def update
  @cuisine = Cuisine.find(params[:id])
  if @cuisine.update_attributes(cuisine_params)
     redirect_to root_path
  else
     redirect_to edit_cuisine_path
  end
end
```

Though this shows the form correctly (showing forms filled with @cuisine and its ingredients' info), after reloading the page the @cuisine object gets deleted even when I don't push the submit button.

Any idea what's going on or how to update nested attributes using `fields_for`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, allow_destroy: true
` enabled :allow_destroy option? And is strong_params (cuisine_params, for example) permitted :_destroy, :_id ?

Comment: Yes I do have them already...

Answer (score 1):

First you should just use `fields_for` like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient_fields|%>
  <%= ingredient_fields.text_area :name %>
  <%= ingredient_fields.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to_remove_fields 'Remove this ingredient', f %>
<% end %>
```

Second you should first check to see if the `cuisine_params` in your controller `permit` those attributes:

```
params.require(:cuisine).permit(:name, ingredients_attributes:[:id, :name, :_destroy])
```

Lastly, make sure your model has this `accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, allow_destroy: true`

Comment: Thank you! the code you wrote here worked for me now :D